# Request with data converted to array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm doing the request and it returns me an Observable correctly, however I want to get these returned objects to be of type Setor, I'm doing a generic method in my ServiceBase passing the type of object to be returned via Generics.

Setor class:

```
import { UUID } from 'angular2-uuid'

export class Setor {
    descricao: string;
    id: UUID;
}
```

setor.component.ts:

```
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SetorService } from './service/setor.service';
import { Setor } from "app/retaguarda/setor/model/setor";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-setor',
  templateUrl: './setor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./setor.component.css']
})

export class SetorComponent implements OnInit {

  setor: Setor;

  private setores: Setor[]; // Lista de setores

  constructor(public setorService: SetorService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setor = new Setor();
  }

  obterTodos(form) {
    let t = this.setorService.obterSetores().subscribe(setores => this.setores = setores);
      console.log(t);
  }
}
```

setor.service.ts:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BaseService } from './../../../shared/service/base/base.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Setor } from "app/retaguarda/setor/model/setor";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class SetorService extends BaseService {

  uriApi: string = 'setor';

  constructor(httpService: Http) {
    super(httpService);
  }

  obterSetores(): Observable<Setor[]> {
    return this.obterTodos<Setor>('setor');
  }
}
```

base.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs'

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class BaseService {

  serviceUrl: string = 'http://localhost:5780/api/';
  headers: Headers;
  options: RequestOptions

  constructor(private httpService: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9'
    });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }

  private getAll<T>(url: string): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpService
      .get(url)
      .map(res => res.json() as T[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  protected obterTodos<T>(url: string): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.getAll(this.serviceUrl + url);
  }

  private post<T>(url: string, data: T): Observable<T> {
    let jsonContent = JSON.stringify(data);
    return this.httpService
      .post(url, jsonContent, this.options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData<T>(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json() as any;
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

JSON returned:

```
    [
        {
        "Descricao": "teste 1",
        "Id": "4b78ade1-39a1-11e7-a8f1-a41f72fdda5d"
        },
        {
        "Descricao": "teste 2",
        "Id": "4b7cb16f-39a1-11e7-a8f1-a41f72fdda5d"
        },
        {
        "Descricao": "teste 3",
        "Id": "4b807449-39a1-11e7-a8f1-a41f72fdda5d"
        }
   ]
```

What is missing so that the return in JSON is deserializable for the Setor class?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @echonax The answer is an array of objects. I need the return to be an array of Setor

Comment: Do you mean your `console.log(t);` gives you not what you want?

Comment: @echonax T is the array of objects, it should be the array of Sectors. This is the precise problem of a strongly typed return.

Comment: Why not just use interfaces, or is there a special reason for use of class? If so, you'd have to first of all modify the class and add a constructor in it.

Comment: @AJT_82 Is my first project with angular, you can suggest the use of interface, would be great, send a response of how should be the code? But I need it to work with the same hierarchy, using generics so you do not need to create more methods for other classes that will go into the future.

Comment: Interfaces is "just a contract" and doesn't exist on runtime, but would be my choice in this case tho :) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html You are sure of the data you are receiving, then you can just cast the response as the type you want. E.g in httprequest you can mark return type to be `Observable<Setor>` and then in your component assign the data to an array of type Setor: `myArray: Setor = []` There's really not anything else to it :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I changed the question with the json that is being returned, can it lead some way forward? From what you said in the last answer I could not understand, can not send a response with the necessary changes?

Comment: Now I am not understanding your last sentence :D I see that the properties in class has upper cases and response lower cases, is that intentional? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 The properties are all lowercase. Your penultimate answer (which contains the link to the typeface tutorial) was complicated for me, I could not understand what I should do, how to proceed with this example. Could you provide a response with the required code changes?

Comment: Sorry, I meant other way around, the JSON properties are upper camel case, for example `Descricao` instead of `descricao`. Is this correct (we need to know to be able to help :) )

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes it is purposeful, the API was developed in .Net in which tme by default the properties are written this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Classes ... First you need to add a constructor to your class in this case, so that we can map to new objects of type `Setor`.

```ts
export class Setor {
  constructor(
    public descricao: string;
    public id: UUID;
  ) {}
}
```

Then we have to map each `Setor` from your response since the properties do not match, otherwise we could use `Object.assign` without explicitly stating properties.

```ts
obterSetores(): Observable<Setor[]> {
  return this.obterTodos<Setor>()
    .map(res => res.map(x => new Setor(x.Descricao, x.Id)))
}
```

That should pretty much do it :)

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/CMvcsLNgK6uDZQDR9gfh?p=preview)**

Comment: worked perfectly!!!!!! But the properties are empty, just need to correct this and everything is right!

Comment: Great, glad to hear! If the properties are empty, there might be some issue with the properties being different still? Since the plunker works fine with the code provided. You just need to check those properties closely, hope you can figure it out. If not, fork the plunker where you recreate the issue and just holler and I can take a look :)